# Adding Macro Code to Word Documents using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, vba, insert, ms-word

Ok so let me explain in detail.

Suppose there is a word file called "Word.doc"

What I want to do is basically use VB.NET for doing the following things :

Open the word document

Add a macro code

For e.g

Add the following macro code to the Word Document

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    Msgbox 
End Sub
```

And then save this document.

Just remember that **I want to insert macro code to a word document** not retreive an already present macro code from a document

Comment: There are examples, if you search. But the default install configuration of Office applications won't allow it - it's a security risk. The user would have to change the setting in the UI. So it's not really a robust approach.

Comment: Doesnt matter I need to achieve this thing.Changing the setting is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple VBA macro that shows how to use the Word object model to add a macro to a document (VB.NET code will be almost identical).

```
Sub NewDocWithCode()
    Dim doc As Document

    Set doc = Application.Documents.Add
    doc.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument").CodeModule.AddFromString _
            "Sub AutoOpen()" & vbLf & _
            "   MsgBox ""It works""" & vbLf & _
            "End Sub"
End Sub
```

Note that running this code requires that access to the VBA project object model is trusted (this needs to be enabled in the trust center in the the Word options).

Answer (score 0):

Working with objects in the VBA Editor through the object model requires a reference to the Microsoft Office VBA Extensibility 5.3 object model which you can find in the COM tab of Project/Add References in Visual Studio.

I like to add an Imports statement to the top of the code so that I don't have to always write out the full namespace qualification:

```
Imports VBE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop
```

An AutoOpen macro needs to be a "public" `Sub` in a normal code module. Assuming you want to add a new code module to the document, use the `VBComponents.Add` method and specify the enumeration type `vbext_ct_StdModule`.

By default, the VBE will name the new module "Module#" - an incrementing number. If you ever need to programmatically address this module again (to see if it exists, for example) it would probably be better to assign a name to it.

Code as a string is added using the `AddFromString` method.

If you're adding code to a document the possibility exists that the document is of type docx, meaning it cannot contain macro code. A document must have the extension docm in order to contain macro code. So you may need to use the SaveAs method on the document to change the file type and the name!

```
Private Sub InsVbaCode_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles InsVbaCode.Click
    'Helper method to get current Word instance or, if none, start one
    GetWordProcess()

    Dim doc As Word.Document = WordApp.ActiveDocument
    Dim vbModule As VBE.VBComponent = doc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule)
    vbModule.Name = "basAddedCode"
    vbModule.CodeModule.AddFromString( _
      "Sub AutoOpen()" & vbLf & _
      "   MsgBox ""Document "" & ActiveDocument.FullName & "" has been opened successfully!""" & vbLf & _
      "End Sub")
    'doc.Save() or doc.SaveAs to change file type and/or name
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I just cant understand two things. Frirst is the GetWordProcess() and second is the 'WordApp'. Can you help me with that also is it possible to add the macro without an opening word .When you mean instance of word , do you mean programmtical instance of word or opening the actual Word. Please bare me and help me out I dont have any idea about using macro and word in .net . Thank You

Comment: That's a different question, and something you should know how to do before you ask how to add a macro to a Word document. There are tons and tons of examples and documentation about how to automate the Word application from VB.NET. I suggest you do some basic research. And read the guidelines for Stack Overflow in the [help]. This is not a free code-writing or tutorial service!

Comment: I am sorry ... I did some research and figured it out mate. Thank You very much mate . But when I try to add the macro to ThisDocument in the Microsoft Word Objects it gave an unknown error .  The  code  I  used  is                        `Dim vbModule As VBE.VBComponent = doc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_Document)
        vbModule.Name = "ThisDocument"`

Comment: Read my Answer again - carefully. ThisDocument is a special *class*, not a normal module. If the macro should be AutoOpen, then you need my code.